# Understanding a proposition of converging nets

Tags: general-topology

> Proposition 4.18 on page 16 of Folland's Real Analysis: If $X$ is a topological space, $E\subset X$, and $x\in X$, then
> (1) $x$ is an accumulation point of $E$ if and only if there exists a net $<x_\alpha>_{\alpha \in A}$ in $E\setminus \{x\}$ that converge to $x$.
> (2)$x\in \overline{E}$ if and only if there exists a net in $E$ that converges to $x$.

The converse part of (2) proposition only differs from (1) by indicating whether or not the set in which the net exists contains the limit. Now, I really don't see how $x_\alpha\in E$ or $x_\alpha \in $ $E\setminus \{x\}$ matters at all, since $\overline{E}=E \cup Acc(E)$. Since we showed in (1) $x$ is an accumulation point it is already in $\overline{E}$.

Comment: I edited because I think you wanted `\setminus `.  If not you can roll it back.

Comment: I think you take $x$ out because otherwise you can take a sequence like the constant sequence $x$, and that's not what is meant by an accumulation point.  I'm not sure what is bothering you,  honestly.

Comment: @pipe Hi thanks for the comment! I basically don't see why we need (2), since x in accumulation points by (1) which is already in the closure. Why do we show that again?

Comment: There could be $x\in E$ which are not accumulation points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the idea of an accumulation point is that you have a *lot* of *different* points getting really close,  vaguely. So it winds up you can get a *non-trivial* net converging to it.  That's why he takes $x$ out.

Otoh, $\overline E$ consists,  as you say, in $E\cup E'$, that's $E$ together with its accumulation points.

Now, to address your concerns,  consider a disk and a point not in the disk.  Say $E=B(0,1)\cup (2,0)\subset \Bbb R^2$.  That point $(2,0)$ not in the disk is not an accumulation point.   But we do want it in $\overline E$.